# Run-Time Error 438 when using UniqueIDS.AddIfAbsent

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am getting a Run-Time Error 438 at the "If Not UniqueIDs.AddIfAbsent(ID)" line when running the following code below: After some research, it seems like the Method/Property is not supported by the UniqueIDs collection. I'm a bit new to all of this so just trying to google the terminology on all of this.

Some steps I took was replacing the .AddIfAbsent with "If Not UniqueIDs.Exists(ID) Then" and also, not using "ActiveSheet" and instead using a Dim ws As Worksheet statement.

One other issue I am facing is the last set of code, specifically the "ID" part of "For Each ID in SortedUniqueIDs", I am getting a compile error: For Each control variable must be Variant or Object"

The code I am using is below:

```
Sub SumUniqueIdentifiers()
'Declare Variables
Dim ID As String
Dim Sum As Double
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim UniqueIDs As New Collection
Dim SortedUniqueIDs As Collection

Sheets("TH").Activate

'Set the last row of the data and Worksheet
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Initialize the sum
Sum = 0

'Loop through the data and sum the values for each unique ID
For i = 3 To LastRow
    ID = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

    'If the ID is new, add to the collection
    If Not UniqueIDs.AddIfAbsent(ID) Then
        Sum = 0
    End If

   'Add the value in the next column to the sum
    Sum = Sum + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value

    'Store the sum in the collection
     UniqueIDs(ID) = Sum
 Next I

'Loop through the collection and print the sums
 For Each ID In SortedUniqueIDs
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 6).Value = ID
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 7).Value = SortedUniqueIDs(ID)
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
Next ID

End Sub
```

Some steps I took was replacing the .AddIfAbsent with "If Not UniqueIDs.Exists(ID) Then" and also, not using "ActiveSheet" and instead using a Dim ws As Worksheet statement.

The goal is sum up unique set of identifiers if I have a series of unique identifiers in column A, each having multiple entries, I want to sum up each unique identifier using the numbers in column D and print them in column F, summed up by each unique identifier

Comment: `Pivot table` can do this.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection` object doesn't support AddIfAbsent. Use `Dictionary` object instead.

```vb
Sub SumUniqueIdentifiers()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim ID As String, i
    Dim Sum As Double
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastR
    '    Dim UniqueIDs As New Collection
    '    Dim SortedUniqueIDs As Collection
    Dim dataR As Range
    Dim UniqueIDs As Object
    Set UniqueIDs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Sheets("TH").Activate
    'Set the last row of the data and Worksheet
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Initialize the sum
    Sum = 0
    'Loop through the data and sum the values for each unique ID
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        ID = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        'If the ID is new, add to the dict
        If Not UniqueIDs.exists(ID) Then
            UniqueIDs(ID) = 0
        Else
            UniqueIDs(ID) = UniqueIDs(ID) + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next i
    'Loop through the collection and print the sums
    LastR = LastRow + 1
    For Each ID In UniqueIDs
        ActiveSheet.Cells(LastR, 6).Value = ID
        ActiveSheet.Cells(LastR + 1, 7).Value = SortedUniqueIDs(ID)
        LastR = LastR + 1
    Next ID
    Set dataR = Range(Cells(LastRow + 1, 6), Cells(LastR - 1, 7))
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=dataR.Columns(1), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange dataR
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest, but a very simple approach (depending on the further use)

Select in column `F` the cells from `row 1` to `row ?` and type in the first cell (? = last used cell row number in column `A`)

```
=SUMIF(A1:A?,"=" & A1:A?,D1:D?)
```

then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (not in 365)

In every line in column `F` the sum of the values of the respective identifier will be shown.